# Is any way to add a line break in the comparing result.txt while compare the difference of two files

Tags: batch-file

I have a catalogue file which could be different between builds/release. I want to do a batch compare to know the difference, particular new in the new build.

I have below code to do the job:

```
findstr /ivg:"C:\CA_MOCKUP\Scripts\compare\old\Load_all.M72" "C:\CA_MOCKUP\Scripts\compare\new\Load_all.M72" > C:\CA_MOCKUP\Scripts\compare\result.txt
```

Now I can have the result.txt showing the difference but they are all in one line without breaking.
Is anyway to have a line break so it will be easy to show the difference of string, basically the line difference

The input data file could be as below:

```
;---- Component: CAVDEV App 0401
;---- Catalog: 8295650401_CAVDEV.MXX
8295650401_CAVDEV.P3A
;---- Component: Tetra Admin App 0003
;---- Catalog: TA_app.mxx
8400000100000500_TetraAdmin.P3A
```

The structure of the file looks like this

```
;---- Component: XXXXX
;---- Catalog: xxxxx.mxx
xxxxxxxxx.xxx
```

My result txt file is showing as below in one line

```
;---- Component: Tetra Admin App 0003;---- Catalog: TA_app.mxx8400000100000500_TetraAdmin.P3A
```

Just tried this command to process the input file

```
TYPE Load_all.M72 > New_Load_all.M72
```

The New_load_all.M72 lack of any lines starting with ;---

Comment: What about showing some sample data? `findstr` returns (non-)matching lines as they appear in the searched file. Perhaps you might also need the `/L` and the `/X` options...

Comment: Show some input data, It can be done, but I need to see the data first, else the script will fail if I have to guess what the data looks like.

Comment: OK I just found out that if the input file has no empty/blank line then the result.txt is showing correct results all strings (lines) displayed as original.

Comment: The files you are reading are more than likely created using unix style line endings, `LF` as opposed to Windows, `CRLF`. The easiest way to deal with this is to use `Type` on the files first, or use `Type` and pipe it through `FindStr`.

Comment: Thanks Compo. You are absolutely correct!

Comment: Tried TYPE command and the file got from this command is just same as any removing blank lines command, the output of the file lack of lines starting ;---- Component: XXXXX or ;---- Catalog: xxxxx.mxx

Comment: @goodywp, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54430374/edit) to show us the commands you are now using, and any other pertinent information.